# I tried to create a docker stack service in which there are multiple OS containers to up, but I'm not able to do this

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-stack

I wanted to create an environment with multiple OSs for ansible lab. I chose docker to achieve that, I have written a docker-compose file to create multiple services using **docker stack**, as soon as I up the stack service all the container going down. I have no idea where to mention the **detach flag** for the stack service. Find the below stack file

```
version: "3"
services:
   ubuntu:
      image: ubuntu
      deploy:
        replicas: 3
        restart_policy:
           condition: on-failure
   centos:
      image: centos
      deploy:
        replicas: 3
        restart_policy:
           condition: on-failure
   alpine:
      image: alpine
      deploy:
        replicas: 2
        restart_policy:
           condition: on-failure
```

Is there any way to overcome my problem or is there any other best solution to set up a ansible lab environment??

Comment: You probably can get better answers for this question on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: Docker stack has no up command. Instead you use `docker stack deploy ...` and it is always detached. If you are using docker compose then `docker-compose up -d ...` starts them in detached state.

Comment: Also docker-compose logs will most likely tell you why containers exited